# Twitter does not open with Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, 22.04

If I try to open Twitter from Firefox, the browser page goes black and nothing happens. When I try to open it directly from the terminal, I get the following Gtk-message twice

```
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I am using 22.04 for the last couple of months and did not have the problem before.
I have tried reinstalling the libcanberra-gtk-module, also installed the 32-bit version of the module(as a last resort) but nothing worked.

Comment: Why the 32 bit version on a 64 bit OS? Is this a new install or an upgrade? Did it work before? Use edit and add the info to the question.

Comment: I have added the edits. I installed the 32-bit version since some other answers to libcanberra problems suggested to do it.

Comment: Clear browser cache, cookies etc. Actually clear everything Firefox knows about Twitter and retry. You can also try to open Twitter while in "incognito" mode.

Comment: I have cleared the cookies related to Twitter, nothing changed.